# Unknown error AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

Well, it's not an error, actually. I have wrote a game. There is only one keyframe on the main timeline (I don't mean one layer, there are lots of them, just like different MovieClips). Currently, I'm not using TextField anywhere, but I want to, because I need to display score on the screen. When adding TextField through Flash CS5 and naming it, when compiling, unknown window appears, you can see it on the picture. Not quite sure what it means. When clicking OK, window disappears but instead of my program there are three dots on the screen, you can see them also. I have no idea, neither of what is this, or how to fix it. Any hints? Thank you in advance :)
By the way, on one of the pictures, you can see what the game should look like. And as I said, it does, until I add some TextField to it.

[image: error message]
[image: result]
[image: that's the screenshot of the game]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it seems that you're using the TLF (text-layout-framework) in your textfield by accident.
this is a RSL (runtime shared library) that the flashplayer has to load before it can show your content. (and i think the dots are some kind of preloader that adobe puts in there ...!?)

but you don't need the TLF, you can just use a simple TextField.
select your score-textfield and choose "classic-text" in the properties window ... think that'll remove the TLF from your project. (if you have more than one TextField, check every one of them for "TLF text" and change it to classic).

Comment: but in this case, i wouldn't be able to enter unicode chars, and that's exactly what i need :SS

Comment: then why i can't enter georgian letters after changing field to classic? :SS

Comment: because you have to embed them first, if it's a dynamic textfield

Comment: example of font embedding in flash cs5: http://www.dotstrosity.net/2010/05/10/flash-cs5-font-embedding-its-totally-different/